# Parse json to string to get value of particular element

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I was trying to get data using geonames api and then find only the names of city.

http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=ksuhiyp&country=in&maxRows=10&style=SHORT.

I got the data but it is in json and i could not find a way to get only names of cities in string format.
Code used-

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ResultInCSV);
string cityname= data["name"].Value<string>();
string  cityname= cityname.Split('\n')[0];
//JObject obj = JObject.Parse(ResultInCSV);
//string FirstLine = (string)obj["name"];
```

Please guide me in getting the name of city from this json.

Json result after clicking on link-

```
{
    "totalResultsCount": 578584,
    "geonames": [{
            "lng": "72.88261",
            "geonameId": 1275339,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Mumbai",
            "toponymName": "Mumbai",
            "lat": "19.07283",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLA"
        }, {
            "lng": "88.36304",
            "geonameId": 1275004,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Kolkata",
            "toponymName": "Kolkata",
            "lat": "22.56263",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLA"
        }, {
            "lng": "77.59369",
            "geonameId": 1277333,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Bengaluru",
            "toponymName": "Bengaluru",
            "lat": "12.97194",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLA"
        }, {
            "lng": "79",
            "geonameId": 1269750,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "India",
            "toponymName": "Republic of India",
            "lat": "22",
            "fcl": "A",
            "fcode": "PCLI"
        }, {
            "lng": "80.27847",
            "geonameId": 1264527,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Chennai",
            "toponymName": "Chennai",
            "lat": "13.08784",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLA"
        }, {
            "lng": "77.23149",
            "geonameId": 1273294,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Delhi",
            "toponymName": "Delhi",
            "lat": "28.65195",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLA"
        }, {
            "lng": "78.45636",
            "geonameId": 1269843,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Hyderabad",
            "toponymName": "Hyderabad",
            "lat": "17.38405",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLA"
        }, {
            "lng": "72.58727",
            "geonameId": 1279233,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Ahmedabad",
            "toponymName": "Ahmedabad",
            "lat": "23.02579",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPL"
        }, {
            "lng": "73.85535",
            "geonameId": 1259229,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "Pune",
            "toponymName": "Pune",
            "lat": "18.51957",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPL"
        }, {
            "lng": "77.22445",
            "geonameId": 1261481,
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "name": "New Delhi",
            "toponymName": "New Delhi",
            "lat": "28.63576",
            "fcl": "P",
            "fcode": "PPLC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your JSON contains an array called "geonames" with a list of cities (plural).  Your code doesn't work because there's no root element called "name" your choices are "totalResultsCount" and "geonames"

Comment: I tried 'var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ResultInCSV);
                string cityname = data["geonames"].Value<string>();' also,still I am not getting.So is there anybetter way to find city names from the json response

Comment: I'd suggest using an editor like Notepad++ or Sublime to format the JSON into a more readable indented format to help you understand its structure better.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as the solution if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code will give you a list of city names

```
IList<string> cityNames = data["geonames"].Select(gn => gn["name"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of below method to get the list of city names:

```
        var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        var a =jo["geonames"].Select(city => city["name"].ToString()).ToList();

        //Or
        foreach (var cityInfo in jo["geonames"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cityInfo["name"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this way:

```
List<string> citynames=new List<string>();
for(i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
{
  citynames.Add(data.geonames[i].name);
}
```